# services.AddSwaggerGen() giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

All I'm trying to do is add swagger to an ASP.Net Core application. I'm watching a tutorial and all I see them do is add `services.AddSwaggerGen();` under the configure services area in the Startup.cs file. Like any normal service like MVC... But I get an error:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'setupAction'...

I don't see anyone supplying any kind of argument to `services.AddSwaggerGen()` so does anyone know what I'm missing here?

I've added the `SwashBuckler.AspNetCore` dependency so swagger is in the application. Just don't know why it's red and giving the above error.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I had problem, that

> IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddSwaggerGen'

I turnes out, that I installed **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger** nuget package instead of **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore**.

In .NET Core 3, there's some issues as discussed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8254). The solution is to add the following to the project file, replacing the prior version.

```
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc2" />
```

Comment: I can't award you the bounty before 24 hours have passed. But you've got one coming up your way, mate.

Comment: Just to add, its now a year later, VS2019 has been released, and now, when I install the latest version (v4.0.1) of "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" it DOES throw this error when building.  If I remove that version, then add v3.x of the same library, then it does build okay.   So, be careful... this stuff has changed again....

Answer (score 20):

For the .Net core project, you need to install Four packages. Better to use Nuget package manager so it takes appropriate needed versions.

```
Microsoft.OpenApi
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI
```

Comment: This was the answer for me, and I explicitly needed to remove Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and go with ONLY these four swagger-related packages.

Comment: This was also the answer for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This happens because the implementation of `AddSwaggerGen()` extension method in ASP.NET Core requires you to provide `Action<SwaggerGenOptions>` argument which serves as setup action. For example:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

You can learn more on how to setup Swagger with ASP.NET Core app [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger).

**UPDATE:** 
In previous versions they had the `AddSwaggerGen()` extension method accepting no arguments, but this call was accompanied with call `ConfigureSwaggerDocument(Action<SwaggerGenOptions> setupAction)`. I guess they just got rid of `ConfigureSwaggerDocument` and added setup action to `AddSwaggerGen()` method. That being said it seems your tutorial shows how to setup obsolete version of the Swagger.

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but as a new update on this question, I just noticed in order to make `AddSwaggerGen` works fine in .NET Core 3, you need to use `OpenApiInfo` instead of `Info`. So your new `AddSwaggerGen` should be something like this:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "The API", Version = "v1" });
});
```

Also you need to add the following to your `using` directives:

```
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
```

Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I'm using .NET 6 and the standard Swagger setup was working fine under the default setup but when I added the above SwaggerDoc setting I get the **Failed To Load API definition** error.  I've tried a few different fixes to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

If you are experiencing this problem while trying to deploy a web app and adding the Swagger spec to API Management in Azure (from Visual Studio) -> check the local path for your repo - if it has a space in it, it will fail.

To fix - move your repo to a different location so the path has no space.
I was using version 6.1.4 of the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package.

Comment: Where to escape the spaces? All you should have to do, as the question asks is include: `services.AddSwaggerGen()` in your Startup class. I found this to fail if the local path to the repo had spaces in it.

Comment: This was a problem for me too. Our Azure DevOps repo name has a space therefore full path of the solution has a space. When I moved the solution to a different path without any space it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It was working for me by install Nuget package of "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" in the current project.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

Answer (score 0):

In my project this problem occured because Swashbuckle.AspNetCore doesn't update. update this package from Tools tab and click Nuget package manager and select manage Nuget package for solution then update the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package to latest version.
thank you