# Why is Microsoft.AspNetCore.App showing as a package not an SDK?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to switch a .netcore3.1 api back to .netcore2.1 so that I can experiment for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861020/failed-resolving-swagger-json-against-file)

I edited the project file to change the TargetFramework to netcoreapp2.1

I can now see Microsoft.NETCore.App ( 2.1.0) in the SDK section of the Dependencies
I expected to also see Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (2.1.1) there since I have that in another project with TargetFramework netcoreapp2.1

[image]

However it was missing so I tried to install it with Nuget.

Now I have Microsoft.AspNetCore.App showing under Packages

[image: packages]

I wound up realizing it was better to start a new project from scratch using the new project Wizard.

There were just too many changes.

I did notice that my netcore3.1 project does not have a SDK folder

[image: Frameworks folder]

Comment: I guess it is just how Microsoft is organising the VS2019 IDE

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is just a design choice made by the folks working on VS2019