# Getting error when publishing webAPI to Azure

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I built my first API and am trying to publish to Azure.

I get the following error **"Be sure that the Startup.cs for your application is calling AddSwaggerGen from within ConfigureServices in order to generate swagger file. Visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=2131205&CLCID=0x409 for more information."**

**Failed to generate swagger file. Error dotnet swagger tofile**

Here is my code from Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "PeopleSearch v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43707733/services-addswaggergen-giving-error

Answer (score 6):

I have been seeing so many questions regarding this issue but not even a single reliable answer. I tried almost all of the solutions with little to no success, the only thing which resolved it for me was the following

- Delete `bin`, `obj`, and `.config` folders (`.config` is a folder, not a file)
- Reopen the project and let the NuGet load in the background (it has removed all the NuGet refs)
- Do a CLEAN and REBUILD

I am not sure if this is going to resolve the issue for anyone else but it did work for me so worth a try.